# Are there any references in mythology/folklore to a concept similar to teleportation?

Tags: myth-identification, folklore, origins, native-american

The earliest mention of teleportation that I can find is a mention of "matter transfer" in [1877](https://bigthink.com/technology-innovation/history-of-teleportation?rebelltitem=1#:%7E:text=The%20very%20first%20mention%20of%20a%20teleportation-like%20device%20in%20fiction%20appears%20to%20have%20been%20in%20Edward%20Page%20Mitchell%27s%20The%20Man%20Without%20a%20Body%2C%20published%20in%20The%20Sun%2C%20a%20New%20York%20City%20daily%2C%20in%201877), but I'm wondering if there's a concept similar to it in folklore. I found something about pukwudgies being able to [appear/disappear at will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pukwudgie#In_mythology), but couldn't find any actual myths relating to this. Can anyone help?

Comment: You would need to distinguish it from both invisibility and very rapid motion, which is the sort of distinction that folklore rarely makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Japanese mythology there is the term 縮地 *[shukuchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shukuchi)*, composed of:

- 縮 : to contract, to shorten
- 地 : earth, location, distance

Shukichi is a collective term for various mythical techniques of rapid movement. The term is used in mythology, but can also be found in texts on Daoism and Buddhism. It is also a popular ability in several manga and anime.

The related term 縮地脈 *suōdìmài* denotes the power of teleportation attributed to some [xians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xian_(Taoism)). Those possessing this ability were believed to be capable of moving vast distances in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

What about Hermes in the greek mythology? His appearances and disappearances are somewhat different from those visions the gods projected simulating their presence, right?